NextAuth(authOptions) is throwing "The types of 'adapter.createUser' are incompatible between these types
I'm currently working on a Next.js 14 project and trying to set up NextAuth using the app/ router. However, I'm encountering a type error that I can't seem to resolve.
Here's my route.ts file:
// ./app/api/[...nextauth]/route.js

import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient;

export const authOptions = {
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "credentials",
            credentials: {
                email: { label: "Email", type: "email" },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
                
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                // check to see if email and password are valid
                if(!credentials || !credentials.email || !credentials.password)
                    return null;

                // Check if the user exists
                const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
                    where: {
                        email: credentials.email
                    }
                });

                if(!user) 
                    return null;

                // Check if passwords match (if user exists)
                const passwordsMatch = user.hashedPassword && await bcrypt.compare(credentials.password, user.hashedPassword);


                if(!passwordsMatch)
                    return null;

                // Return user object if everything is valid
                return user;
            }
        })
    ],
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt' as const // Explicitly type as 'jwt'
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
};

export const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }

this yeilds me this error:
Argument of type '{ adapter: Adapter; providers: CredentialsConfig<{ email: { label: string; type: string; }; password: { label: string; type: string; }; }>[]; session: { strategy: "jwt"; }; secret: string | undefined; debug: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AuthOptions'.
  The types of 'adapter.createUser' are incompatible between these types.
    Type '((user: AdapterUser) => Awaitable<AdapterUser>) | undefined' is not assignable to type '((user: Omit<AdapterUser, "id">) => Awaitable<AdapterUser>) | undefined'.
      Type '(user: AdapterUser) => Awaitable<AdapterUser>' is not assignable to type '(user: Omit<AdapterUser, "id">) => Awaitable<AdapterUser>'.
        Types of parameters 'user' and 'user' are incompatible.
          Property 'id' is missing in type 'Omit<AdapterUser, "id">' but required in type 'AdapterUser'.

I have tried to change
export const authOptions = {

to
export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {

That changes the error to
Type 'import("c:/<path>@auth/core/adapters").Adapter' is not assignable to type 'import("c:/<path>/node_modules/next-auth/adapters").Adapter'.
  Types of property 'createUser' are incompatible.
    Type '((user: AdapterUser) => Awaitable<AdapterUser>) | undefined' is not assignable to type '((user: Omit<AdapterUser, "id">) => Awaitable<AdapterUser>) | undefined'.
      Type '(user: AdapterUser) => Awaitable<AdapterUser>' is not assignable to type '(user: Omit<AdapterUser, "id">) => Awaitable<AdapterUser>'.
        Types of parameters 'user' and 'user' are incompatible.
          Property 'id' is missing in type 'Omit<AdapterUser, "id">' but required in type 'AdapterUser'.

I don't have enough of idea aabout what I am doing and whe things turn out as they do.. please help me.

What versions are your @auth/ and next-auth?

Explicitly define the type of the adapter:
import { Adapter } from "next-auth/adapters";

adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma) as Adapter

